# Logical condition while subsetting not giving correct values

Tags: r, logic, subset

I wanted to subset data frame `project` I was working with, using a logical. I am getting a paradoxical result. The part of the logical preceding the `ROLL.NO.` argument is irrelevant to the question. Sorry, I could not give a reproducible example. Do let me know how can I make this question reproducible without having to show the entire 393 entries of the relevant columns in my data frame.`D14` and `DC31` are simple integer values, with some values being `NA`.

```
 culprits<-project$ROLL.NO.[(project$DC31==1&project$D14==2)|(project$DC31==2&project$D14==1)&!is.na(project$DC31)&!is.na(project$D14)]
culprits
 [1] 3138 3129 3129 3135 3135 3136 3120 3126 3133 3125 3125 3125 3132 3132 3123 3123 3131
 project$HOUSE.NO[(project$DC31==1&project$D14==2)|(project$DC31==2&project$D14==1)&!is.na(project$DC31)&!is.na(project$D14)&project$ROLL.NO.==3131]
[1] "14/132" "14/176" "16/133" "14/111" "14/252"
> project$HOUSE.NO[(project$DC31==1&project$D14==2)|(project$DC31==2&project$D14==1)&!is.na(project$DC31)&!is.na(project$D14)&project$ROLL.NO.==3129]
[1] "14/132" "15/162" "14/176" "16/133" "14/111"
> project$ROLL.NO.[(project$DC31==1&project$D14==2)|(project$DC31==2&project$D14==1)&!is.na(project$DC31)&!is.na(project$D14)&project$ROLL.NO.==3136]
[1] 3129 3136 3120 3123 3123
 project$ROLL.NO.[(project$DC31==1&project$D14==2)|(project$DC31==2&project$D14==1)&!is.na(project$DC31)&!is.na(project$D14)&project$ROLL.NO.==3125]
[1] 3129 3120 3125 3125 3125 3123 3123
project$ROLL.NO.[project$ROLL.NO.==3136]
[1] 3136 3136 3136 3136 3136 3136 3136 3136 3136
```

I tried to understand what was going wrong in my code and I have also included the results of those queries. When `project$ROLL.NO.==3136` is `FALSE` for any other `ROLL.NO.`, I fail to see why are other `ROLL.NO.` called when other arguments are added with an `&` with it. Moreover, the same three entries erroneously repeat along with any called `ROLL.NO.` There are no `NA` values in the `ROLL.NO.` column. And the length of the logical vectors in each of the conditions is the same, hence no recycling. Do let me know if additional information needs to be given.

ADDENDUM

```
project <-  structure(list(ROLL.NO. = c(3138L, 3138L, 3138L, 3138L, 3138L, 
3138L, 3138L, 3138L, 3138L, 3138L, 3138L, 3138L, 3138L, 3138L, 
3138L, 3138L, 3138L, 3138L, 3138L, 3138L, 3138L, 3129L, 3129L, 
3129L, 3129L, 3129L, 3129L, 3129L, 3129L, 3129L, 3129L, 3129L, 
3129L, 3129L, 3129L, 3129L, 3129L, 3129L, 3129L, 3129L, 3129L, 
3129L, 3129L, 3129L, 3121L, 3121L, 3121L, 3121L, 3121L, 3121L
), DC31 = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), D14 = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), HOUSE.NO = c("14/274", 
"14/259", "14/217", "14/258", "14/306", "14/300", "14/96", "14/166", 
"14/69", "14/68", "14/16", "14/93", "14/130", "14/321", "14/324", 
"14/139", "14/314", "14/323", "14/208", "14/78", "14/150", "14/155", 
"14/102", "14/132", "14/159", "14/163", "14/165", "14/146", "14/148", 
"14/104", "14/56", "14/53", "14/99", "14/48", "15/164", "15/148", 
"15/158", "15/107", "15/160", "15/162", "15/243", "15/66", "15/249", 
"15/86", "14/388", "14/396", "14/431", "14/401", "14/103", "15/36"
)), .Names = c("ROLL.NO.", "DC31", "D14", "HOUSE.NO"), row.names = c(NA, 
50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @rawr Added to the question. Not sure if the aberrants are included.

Comment: so basically you are doing `TRUE | TRUE & FALSE` where you expect this to be false (but it is true), but what you really want is `(TRUE | TRUE) & FALSE` which is false?

Comment: Why would the former be TRUE?

Comment: Can you compile both of these as answer? And I fail to see how the latter would create a problem in my case.

Comment: from `?\`|\``, `See ?Syntax for the precedence of these operators: unlike many other languages (including S) the AND and OR operators do not have the same precedence (the AND operators have higher precedence than the OR operators).` so for `TRUE | TRUE &  FALSE`, `TRUE & FALSE` is evaluated first and the expression becomes `TRUE | FALSE`

Comment: it doesn't seem to be, just pointing it out since you say you have NA, you should be aware of it. you need to test for `NA` using `is.na` since `==` will not work as expected

Comment: Okay. Thanks it settles all. Can you post these as an answer just so that this question isn't filed under the unanswered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `?base::Logic`, `help('&')`, `help('|')`, etc

> See `Syntax` for the precedence of these operators: unlike many other languages (including S) the AND and OR operators do not have the same precedence (the AND operators have higher precedence than the OR operators).

which explains why

```
TRUE | TRUE & FALSE
# [1] TRUE
```

which is essentially

```
TRUE | (TRUE & FALSE)
```

which is also true, and a simplification of what you are doing here:

```
(project$DC31==1&project$D14==2) |
  (project$DC31==2&project$D14==1) &
  !is.na(project$DC31) &
  !is.na(project$D14) &
  project$ROLL.NO. == 3131
```

since you expect the result only to contain some `project$ROLL.NO. == 3131` I assume, so even if some of these are false, if one or more `OR` is true, you may get some that are not `ROLL.NO.` which are not `3131`

Also note that `!` has a higher precedence than logicals